# iphone - How to track events with Google Analytics EasyTracker?

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I figure out how to track "page views" in the iOS app using the Google Analytics Library Easy Tracker.

But I can't seem to find the way to track taps in the screen, tapping buttons exactly.

Can someone lend me a hand on this?

Thanks

Comment: Anyone has used the library and has tracked events?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you press the button ..in your `IBAction` method ..call this

```
 if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackEvent:@"my_category"
                                       action:@"my_action"
                                        label:@"my_label"
                                        value:-1
                                   withError:&error]) {
    // Handle error here
  }
```

you can change category name,action name and label name to your need

Comment: But that's using Google Analytics library, I want to use EasyTracker. In the documentation says not to use both at the same time, have you use this, does it work?

Comment: That's the way to do it .. the EasyTracker is a wrapper for the GANTracker singleton so you are able to call the GANTracker methods too.